# Collision detection in C++ SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm creating a Spaceshooter game where the enemy should disappear if it collides with the bullet. I have an issue where sometimes the collision works, but sometimes it doesn't. I created the collision check function independently and tried to call it as many times as possible during the game (see the update function) but still it doesn't solve the issue. Could anyone help? I'm attaching the main loop and the game loop. Or do you have any tips on how I can debug this issue (i.e. debugging non-reproducible issues like this)? I also attach the issue in a picture, where the bullet goes through the enemy.

[image]

main.cpp

```
#include "player.h"

#include "Game.h"
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1920, 1080), "Aldo game", Style::Default);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    Game game(&window);
    sf::Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("Textures/background1.jpg");
    sf::Sprite s(t);

    s.setScale(1920 / s.getGlobalBounds().width, 1080 / s.getGlobalBounds().height);
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == Keyboard::Escape)
                window.close();
        }

        game.Update();
        game.Draw(s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

//constructor
Game::Game(RenderWindow* window) {
    this->window = window;
    this->window->setFramerateLimit(60);
    //Init textures
    playerTexture.loadFromFile("Textures/ship.png");
    bulletTexture.loadFromFile("Textures/bullet.png");
    enemyTexture.loadFromFile("Textures/bullet.png");

    //Init fonts
    this->font.loadFromFile("Fonts/Dosis-Light.ttf");

    //Init player(s)
    players.push_back(Player(&playerTexture, &bulletTexture));
    players.push_back(Player(&playerTexture, &bulletTexture, Keyboard::I,
        Keyboard::K, Keyboard::J, Keyboard::L, Keyboard::RShift));

    //Init enemies
    enemies.push_back(Enemy(
        &enemyTexture,
        this->window->getSize(),
        Vector2f(0.f, 0.f),
        Vector2f(-1.f, 0.f),
        Vector2f(0.1f, 0.1f),
        0,
        1,
        3,
        1
    ));
    
    this->InitUI();

}
//destructor
Game::~Game() {

}

//function definitions


void Game::InitUI() {
    Text tempText;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->players.size(); i++) {
        tempText.setFont(font);
        tempText.setCharacterSize(24);
        tempText.setFillColor(Color::White);
        tempText.setString(std::to_string(i));

        this->followPlayerTexts.push_back(tempText);

        //Static text init
        tempText.setFont(font);
        tempText.setCharacterSize(24);
        tempText.setOutlineColor(Color::White);
        tempText.setString("N/A");

        this->staticPlayerTexts.push_back(tempText);
    }
}

void Game::UpdateUI() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->followPlayerTexts.size(); i++) {
        float movingTextxPos = this->players[i].getPosition().x + (this->players[i].getSize().x / 2 * this->players[i].getScale().x);
        float movingTextyPos = this->players[i].getPosition().y;
        Vector2f textPos = { movingTextxPos, movingTextyPos };
        this->followPlayerTexts[i].setPosition(textPos);
        this->followPlayerTexts[i].setString(std::to_string(i) + " | " + players[i].getHpAsString());
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->staticPlayerTexts.size(); i++) {
        this->staticPlayerTexts[i].setPosition(1920/2, 0);
        this->staticPlayerTexts[i].setString("N/A");
    }
}

void Game::DrawUI() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->followPlayerTexts.size(); i++)
    {
        this->window->draw(this->followPlayerTexts[i]);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->staticPlayerTexts.size(); i++)
    {
        this->window->draw(this->staticPlayerTexts[i]);
    }
}

void Game::Update() {
    // Update Players
    for (size_t i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
    {
        players[i].Update(this->window);
    }

    this->CheckCollision();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        this->enemies[i].Update();
        //Erase enemies if it goes out of frame, and reduce player HP
        if (this->enemies.size() > 0){
            if (this->enemies[i].getPosition().x < 0)
            {
                this->enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);
                for (size_t j = 0; j < this->players.size(); j++)
                {
                    players[j].reduceHP();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this->CheckCollision();


    if (enemies.size() < enemyMax && enemyTimer < enemyTimerMax) {
        enemies.push_back(Enemy(
            &enemyTexture,
            this->window->getSize(),
            Vector2f(0.f, 0.f),
            Vector2f(-1.f, 0.f),
            Vector2f(0.1f, 0.1f),
            0,
            1,
            3,
            1
        ));
        enemyTimer = enemyTimer + 1.0f;
    }
    else {
        enemyTimer = 0.f;
    }
    this->CheckCollision();

    this->UpdateUI();
}

void Game::Draw(sf::Sprite background) {
    this->window->clear();
    window->draw(background);
    this->DrawPlayers();
    this->DrawEnemies();
    this->DrawUI();
    this->window->display();
}

void Game::DrawPlayers()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->players.size(); i++)
    {
        players[i].Draw(*this->window);
    }
}

void Game::DrawEnemies()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        this->enemies[i].Draw(*this->window);
    }
}


void Game::CheckCollision() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->players.size(); i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < this->enemies.size(); j++)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < this->players[i].getBullets().size(); k++) {
                if (this->players[i].getBullets()[k].getGlobalBounds().intersects(this->enemies[j].getGlobalBounds())) {
                    this->enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your image, the bullet is clearly _not_ intersecting with the enemy.  If I were to guess, your game is drawing a bullet on one side of the enemy, and in the following frame on the other.

Comment: Your question is a bit bloated, create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Specifically if you think the error is in the game logic, dont include drawing code etc. I think Bullet/Enemy classes could help here? (also i wouldnt use this-> with no reason, it only distracts).